# Infinite asyncIterator is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous

So I am trying to create an infinite asyncIterator / generator.
The code is supposed to yield "Hello" and "Hi" to the 'for await of' loop and then wait forever for next value. The problem is that it does not wait for the third value nor prints 2 after loop and terminates without errors.

Running with ts-node on Node v12.14.0.

```
 class Source<T> {

    _data: T[] = [];
    _queue: ((val: T) => void)[] = [];

    send(val: T) {
        if (this._queue.length > 0) {
            this._queue.shift()!(val);
        } else {
            this._data.push(val);
        }
    }

    next(): Promise<{ done: boolean, value: T }> {
        return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
            if (this._data.length > 0) {
                resolve({ done: false, value: this._data.shift()! });
            } else {
                this._queue.push(value => resolve({ done: false, value }));
            }
        });
    }

    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        return this;
    }

}

(async () => {
    const s = new Source<String>();
    s.send("Hello");
    s.send("Hi");

    console.log(1);

    for await (let str of s) {
        console.log(str);
    }

    console.log(2);
})();
```

Comment: You could take the compiled js and step through the code in the debugger.

Comment: Hmm, I just did that (stepped through with a debugger).  I can't explain this behavior. 

Comment: It looks like unresolved promises don't prevent a program from exiting.  `new Promise(() => {}).then(() => console.log('foo'));` exits immediately.  What I find strange is that as long as you keep calling `s.send()`, the program will remain running.  Maybe this is because as soon as you call `s.send()`, a Promise in the queue resolves, and so the program has more code to run?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it does not wait for the third value*"? There is no third value in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unresolved* promises will not block exiting the process.  Take a look at [this](https://github.com/nodejs/promises-debugging/issues/16).

As long as there is a resolved promise and a chain that follows it, the process will continue to run.  Since you call `s.send()` a couple times before the `for await`, the first two iterations in the loop have resolved promises, and thus more code to run.  After this, it's waiting on an unresolved promise, which makes your call to `(async () => { ... })()` an unresolved promise.  With no more code running, the process exits.

To get around this, you could do something nasty like `setInterval(() => {}, 999999999)`.  As long as there is a timeout scheduled, the process will not exit.

It took me a while to figure out in what case we would want this behavior--not waiting until all promises have been resolved or rejected before exiting.

```js
let p1 = Promise.resolve(1),
    p2 = new Promise(() => {}).then(Promise.resolve(2)),
    p3 = Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(console.log);
```

`p2` will never resolve, and `p3`'s `Promise.race()` call does not cancel `p2`'s `then()`. However, we would expect this program to print `1` and then exit.

Comment: `(async () => {
    setInterval(() => {}, 999999);
    ...
}
`
solved the problem